# can't insert any data to database using controller [EF Core]

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am working on my Uni project that uses database with two tables: `Role` and `User`.
`Users.RoleId` is a foreign key referring to `Role.Id`
I generated Controllers for each table/model classes using Scaffolding template "MVC Model with views using Entity Framework", so `RolesControler.cs` and `UsersControler.cs` are almost the same.

I can create, edit or delete roles using different views which can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9JfJ.png).
As you can see, new role [is inserted into the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaiKJ.png).

While trying to do the exact thing using views specified for `UsersController.cs` I can't add or modify a user. I fill all the inputs but submitting won't give any results, page is not refreshing (not redirecting to `index.cshtml`), no data is added to the database, just nothing happens, [I can click "Create" button forever.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjjBV.png)
I tried adding users manually using SQL query in SQL Server Object Explorer and they appear on the list. What's interesting I can delete them using `Delete` method. The button reacts, redirect me to main page and deletes record from database.

Also while trying to create new User I can only select Roles that already exists - which is intended - but that suggests that the referrence between `User.RoleId` and `Role.Id` is done properly.

Here is code for `Create` method in `UsersControler.cs`:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Surname,DateOfBirth,Login,RoleId,IsDeleted")] User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["RoleId"] = new SelectList(_context.Roles, "Id", "Id", user.RoleId);
            return View(user);
        }
```

I don't really know why everything is fine for `Role` table/model, but when it comes to `User` I can only delete records that already exist in database.

**EDIT:**
I tried inserting new user using invalid date (year 32121) and [validation error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0UD9.png), which for me indicates that the submit button reacts and validates input data, but if it's valid, it doesn't insert the record to database and doesn't redirect into index page.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask what your model classes for `Role` and `User` look like? I suspect that your data types are not matching. I have a nearly similar problem as you, only that I cannot even enter the foreign key

Comment: `Role` class contains  `public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; } = new List<User>();`, and `User` class contains `public int RoleId { get; set; }` and `public virtual Role Role { get; set; } = null!;`

Comment: I think you have to include the principal key for the `Role` class. As it stands, you are only having the foreign key `RoleId` in `User` but no principal key to match with it in the `Role` class. Or you should have a reference navigation property `Role` inside `User` class so that the relationship can be established. See [here](www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships)

Comment: ```User``` class already has a reference navigation property which in this case is: ```public Role Role {get;set;}```, so I really believe that the relationship has been established properly. As I said before, submit button in ```Create``` view for ```UsersController``` doesn't make any changes (expected: adding record(user) to database and redirect to index page), while similar scenario works for that view for ```RolesController```.